# MongoDB $project embedded document to root level

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Using the aggregate pipeline, I am trying to project an embedded document to the root level **WITHOUT projecting each field individually.**

For example, I want to project `name` from this collection to the root level:

```
[
    {
        _id: "1",
        name: {
            firstName: "John",
            lastname: "Peters"
        }
    },
    {
        _id: "2",
        name: {
            firstName: "Mary",
            lastname: "Jones"
        }
    }
]
```

This is what I am looking for:

```
[
    {
        firstName: "John",
        lastname: "Peters"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Mary",
        lastname: "Jones"
    }
]
```

Is there a way to do this without projecting each field individually? I don't want to have to do this:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project : {
                "_id" : 0,
                "firstName" : "$name.firstName",
                "lastName" : "$name.lastName"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What's the rationale behind not taking the above approach?

Comment: use - [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT), you won't get it in the top most level, but all the variables can be contained under a single field.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MongoDB 3.4 has the new stage in aggregation pipeline - `$replaceRoot`, which does exactly what was asked.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution which uses JavaScript variable.

```
# Set Object for what to project
var projectWhat = {'_id' : 0};

# Fill Object with keys
Object.keys(db.coll.findOne().name).forEach(function(x){
    projectWhat[x] = "$name." + x;
});

# Do Aggregate
db.coll.aggregate([{$project : projectWhat}])
```

And the output will be

```
{ "firstName" : "John", "lastname" : "Peters" }
{ "firstName" : "Mary", "lastname" : "Jones" }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$replaceRoot` like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $replaceRoot : {
                newRoot: {"$name"}
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Also if you have a field in the root document you want to *retain* you can use a `$mergeObjects` to combine it with your embedded object:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $replaceRoot : {
                newRoot: {
                   $mergeObjects: [
                      {"_id": "$_id"},
                      "$name"
                   ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be newRoot: "$name", rather than newRoot: {"$name"} ?

Answer (score 1):

This may be achieved by using `$set` to update all documents with the values in the `name` sub-document:

```
db.collection.find({ "name": {"$exists": 1 } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    var setName = {};
    for ( var k in doc.name ) {
        setName[k] = doc.name[k];
    }
    db.collection.update(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        { "$set": setName, "$unset": "name" }
    );
})
```

While I'll recommend you use `$project` because it would be more performant than this solution, I can understand why you wouldn't want to use `$project`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Mongo 4.2`, the [`$replaceWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/#pipe._S_replaceWith) aggregation operator can be used to replace a document by another (in our case by a sub-document):

```
// { _id: "1", name: { firstName: "John", lastname: "Peters" } }
// { _id: "2", name: { firstName: "Mary", lastname: "Jones"  } }
db.collection.aggregate({ $replaceWith: "$name" })
// { firstName: "John", lastname: "Peters" }
// { firstName: "Mary", lastname: "Jones" }
```